# Returning files from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file

Beginner rails question: **How does one return a file from a controller in rails?**

I'm familiar with returning/rendering JSON objects. However I've never returned/rendered a file w/ an arbitrary extension.

From reading around SO it sounds like `render :nothing => true` could help. I'm just looking for some guidance or relevant documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213957/exposing-files-from-a-service-through-a-rails-application

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the built-in rails [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_file) or [send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data) method.

To stream a file (e.g. for a file proxy endpoint), use send_file:

```
send_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/path/to/file/on/server",
  :filename => "client-suggested-filename",
  :type => "mime/type")
```

To stream generated data (e.g. for a generated pdf), use send_data:

```
send_data(your_data,
  :filename => "client-suggested-filename",
  :type => "mime/type")
```

The file extension and mime type don't have to match up, but they probably should just to conform to end user expectations. For example, if you are sending with a mime type of `application/pdf`, you should really set the `:filename` to `something.pdf`.

If you're not sure what the mime type is for the file you are sending, you can check [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) or use the [mime-types](http://mime-types.rubyforge.org/) gem. (Or if you are reading from a database that stores the mime type, use that).